# Code to exit a blackberry browser

Tags: blackberry, browser

Can anyone help me with code to exit a browser? I know how to invoke a browser:

```
String url = ("http://ww.google.com/");

         BrowserSession BS = Browser.getDefaultSession(); //A BrowserSession is created
                BS.displayPage(url);
```

Now how do you close the browser? I've been looking everywhere but cannot find any code to close a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If u press "END" key on device, the browser will close.  But MultiTasking function is going on.
So press "ESCAPE" Key on device.

or

Use below code:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time)
{
    switch(Keypad.key(keycode))
    {
        case Keypad.KEY_END:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        case Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Gabesh, but I am looking for code to close the browser automaticallly without having to press a button. Is that possible?